# Issues with Domain Access module

Tags: rules, domain-access

Using Drupal 8.9.13. I cannot seem to make the site I am building functional with the Domain suite of modules installed. Symptoms:
After installing and enabling the Domain module, the site generates a general error when I log in. There is an error in the dblog:

TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\Core\Plugin\Context\ContextHandler::Drupal\Core\Plugin\Context{closure}() must implement interface Drupal\Core\Plugin\Context\ContextInterface, null given in Drupal\Core\Plugin\Context\ContextHandler->Drupal\Core\Plugin\Context{closure}() (line 76 of C:\Users\eugene\Sites\acquia\newfaces\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Plugin\Context\ContextHandler.php)

I narrowed it down to some kind of conflict between Layout builder module and Domain module. If either one is uninstalled, the error is gone. When Layout builder is uninstalled I can create domain records and then re-enable Layout builder. At this point there will be no errors.

When I continue to enable other modules in the domain suite, they seem to install fine, until I install Domain Source module. It seems to be in some conflict with the rules module. I cannot view user profile, including my own with the error indicating that memory of 512M is exhausted (no error in the dblog). Uninstalling either modules removes the error condition.

Please help. I don't see any similar issues here.

Comment: Did you try to set memory_limit = 1G in php.ini. Maybe you make some debugging output that is so memory greedy?

Comment: It seems it does not matter what the setting is. It started as 256M, I increased it to 512

Comment: It does matter but you should investigate what the reason for high memory consumtion is.

Comment: I did increase memory limit to1024M. When I attempt to browse to my own user page I get the following errors:
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in C:\Users\eugene\Sites\acquia\newfaces\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Routing\CompiledRoute.php on line 162
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in C:\Users\eugene\Sites\acquia\newfaces\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Database\Connection.php on line 1051

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in C:\Users\eugene\Sites\acquia\newfaces\web\core\includes\errors.inc on line 26
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: I just uninstalled Rules module (dev version, the recommended version ruins the block visibility settings) and no error. But I do need Rules.

Comment: There are maybe incompatibility issues between Rules and other modules. Another solution: you code just your own module with rules. Do you know Drupal hooks?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is over my skill level. I am looking for help...

Comment: I opened an issue in Rules queue https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/issues/3208189. TR was able to quickly find a cause for the error: the two rules context provider plugins which somehow conflict with domain module.

Comment: Ok, so the issue is resolved? Fine :-)